# Using ISO7816d4Padding with a BlockCipher in Java

Tags: java, cryptography, padding, bouncycastle, jca

I am using the BC provider from my crypto application. 
I want to know if there is anyway to transform a Cipher object (inherent from the JCA) to a BlockCipher object (inherent to BC). The reason behind this is because I need  ISO7816d4Padding, which is not found in the JCA one.

Comment: Why transform it if you can simply instantiate some `BlockCipher` with the padding that you need?

Comment: @ArtjomB. No need for that :)

Answer (score 1):

Sure thing, you can just use ECB mode by instantiating the block cipher as `"<ciphername>/ECB/NoPadding"` where `<ciphername>` is of course the name of the cipher. In your case it is probably `"DESede"`  or `"AES"`. Then if you feed it a single 8 or 16 byte block you will get precisely one encrypted or decrypted block returned.

However, in your case I would just use:

```
Cipher iso = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/ISO7816-4Padding");
```

after registering the Bouncy Castle provider.